# Python Flask select data within 20 km

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy

i have develop a rest service with python, flask and sqlAlchemy. I retrive all data by sqlite db.
Now i would like to create a service that select on sqlite db all record within 20 km respect my position.
All record into db have a lato long value.

Any help?
Thanks

Comment: This question is too broad, but if you are doing anything with geospatial data and sqlalchemy I would highly recommend postgis + geoalchemy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe sqlAlchemy is not the right choice for storage, instead, an alternative could be Apache Solr, Elasticsearch, or even the new (and still not stable, Redis 3.2, but might take a while for that to become stable, yet).

On another note, doing a quick search in Google, this popped out: http://geoalchemy-2.readthedocs.io/en/0.3/, looks like an extension to sqlAlchemy and could very well fit your needs.

I hope I have shed some light into your issue or at least pointed you to a better direction.

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice. Also I thought to a mathematical algorithm for calculating the distance by my coordinate